# python raise exception where there looks not exception?

Tags: python, exception

I have a problem that:

1. when testing on flask there is not exception
2. after put online by gunicorn+gevent, they raise an exception at following code

-

```
try:
    req_dict = request.args.to_dict()

    req_desc = copy.copy(req_dict)
    temp_card_pwd = str(req_desc['cardpwd'])
    req_desc['cardpwd'] = temp_card_pwd.replace(temp_card_pwd[5:9], "****")

    log.info('接收到一条请求信息(charge_in##) %s' % req_desc)
    request_type = str(req_dict['command'])
    charge_acct = str(req_dict['telephone'])
    card_pwd = str(req_dict['cardpwd'])

    res_dict = req_validate(request_type, card_pwd, charge_acct)
    if res_dict['errcode'] == 0:
        log.info('准备充值(charge_begin##)...%s '% req_desc)
        time_start = time.time()
        acct_charge = True
        charge_res = charge(req_desc, card_pwd, charge_acct)
        res_dict['body'] = charge_res
        log.info('充值结果(charge_end##)：请求：%s, 结果：%s 耗时：%s' % (req_desc, res_dict,
                                                            int((time.time() - time_start)*1000)))
    else:
        log.warning('返回异常请求结果（charge_out##）：请求：%s 结果：%s' % (req_desc, res_dict))
except Exception as e:
    if acct_charge:
        code = 1007
        msg = '充值异常！%s' % e
    else:
        code = 1006
        msg = '传入参数错误! %s' % e
    res_dict = {'errcode': code, 'msg': msg, 'body': None}
    log.warning('返回异常请求结果（charge_exception##）：请求参数异常！请核对后再发！%s' % res_dict)
```

**the exception is**

```
2017-08-04 06:47:50,441 yidongserver.py[line:49] WARNING: [channel_name:yidongApp] 返回异常请求结果（charge_exception##）：请求参数异常！请核对后再发！{'errcode': 1006, 'msg': '传入参数错误', 'body': None}

2017-08-04 06:47:50,445 yidongserver.py[line:25] INFO: [channel_name:yidongApp] 接收到一条请求信息(charge_in##) {'request_id': 'HF111708041450260032', 'card_id': '17356104229493840', 'telephone': '152***94608', 'cardpwd': '42381****349361850', 'money': '100', 'callbackurl': '', 'command': 'charge', 'channel_id': 'LTAppRY'}
```

**Although raise this exception, this charge request still SUCCESS in charge, and return ONCE**

pls help to solve this warning exception! thanks!

Comment: 传入参数错误! %s' % e, the exception data is added locally after。maybe i should correct it and check what's the exception. Anyway if the request param is correct, this exception should not be happen online ONLY isn't it?

Comment: can't read the exception info, and your code is not printing the *type* and *traceback* either. So at least change your exception handler to print/log more details to see what the exact error is and where it is coming from. I suspect somewhere in the ``req_validate`` function but you didn't tell what that thing does.

Comment: Try using `log.exception` instead of formatting your own log message. Somehow the actual exception data is getting truncated in the `msg` field of the logged `res_dict` (everything after the "!").